# Android: DatePicker style with Holo and AppCompat dialog.

Tags: java, android

Currently, my datepicker dialogue looks like this. But this is using the `Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog` theme.

[image]

But I would like to achieve the following, with the title and the buttons using the AppCompat dialog style (given my understanding, it is the material theme), yet with the center spinners still maintaining the non-material style (the selections).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved the issue!**

Instead of going through the trouble of styling the dialog box, I used `AlertDialog` and inflated the layout containing the `DatePicker`.

**datepicker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/daily_datepicker"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the code-behind...

```
public AlertDialog.Builder displayDailyOverviewDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datepicker, null);

        dialog.setTitle("Set Daily Overview");
        dialog.setView(dialogView);

        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.daily_datepicker);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        dp.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        dp.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
        dp.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dp.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        dialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

        dialog.create();

        return dialog;
    }
```